# Android Oreo and higher Downtime of Keyevent always 0

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, keyevent, downtime

In my app i use a receiver to receive the media button clicks of a bluetooth headset.
When i log the whole KeyEvent i get the following log:

```
E/KeyEvent: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY, scanCode=200, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=35925738, downTime=35925707, deviceId=9, source=0x101 }
```

In the end of this line you can see that I get a value for the downTime. Sadly and here also comes my problem i do only get a downtime when i connect my bluetooth headset with devices with an Android Version < than Android Oreo. On Devices with Android Oreo or Android Pie i always get

```
downTime=0
```

Does someone know why this is happening or why they changed it? And does somebody know how it is possible to get a Downtime for devices with Android Oreo and higher?

Many thanks in advance and greetings! :)

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the total Downtime regarding `KeyEvent` use:

```
event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime()
```

The returned value is in milliseconds

More info

- [getEventTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getEventTime())
- [getDownTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#getDownTime())